# Add new row to pyspark dataframe based on values

Tags: pyspark

I have got dataframe like this:

```
client_username|workstation|session_duration|access_point_name|start_date|
XX1@AD         |Apple      |1.55            |idf_1            |2019-06-01|
XX2@AD         |Apple      |30.12           |idf_2            |2019-06-04|
XX3@AD         |Apple      |78.25           |idf_3            |2019-06-02|
XX4@AD         |Apple      |0.45            |idf_1            |2019-06-02|
XX1@AD         |Apple      |23.11           |idf_1            |2019-06-02|

client_username - id of user in domain
workstation - user workstation
session_duration - duration (in hours) of the active session (user logged on hist host)
access_point_name - the name of access point that supplies the network to users host
start_date - start session
```

I would like to achieve dataframe like this:

```
client_username|workstation|session_duration|access_point_name|start_date|
XX1@AD         |Apple      |1.55            |idf_1            |2019-06-01|
XX2@AD         |Apple      |8               |idf_2            |2019-06-04|
XX2@AD         |Apple      |8               |idf_2            |2019-06-05|
XX3@AD         |Apple      |8               |idf_3            |2019-06-02|
XX3@AD         |Apple      |8               |idf_3            |2019-06-03|
XX3@AD         |Apple      |8               |idf_3            |2019-06-04|
XX3@AD         |Apple      |8               |idf_3            |2019-06-05|
XX4@AD         |Apple      |0.45            |idf_1            |2019-06-02|
XX1@AD         |Apple      |23.11           |idf_1            |2019-06-02|
```

The idea is as follows:
* if the length of session is over 24 hours, but less than 48 hours I would like change it:

```
XX2@AD         |Apple      |30.12           |idf_2            |2019-06-04|
```

to it:

```
XX2@AD         |Apple      |8               |idf_2            |2019-06-04|
XX2@AD         |Apple      |8               |idf_2            |2019-06-05|
```

The duration of the session changes to 8 hours, but the number of days increases to two days (2019-06-04 and 2019-06-05).
Analytical situations for duration above 48 hours (3 days), 72 hours (4 days) etc.

I'm starting to learn pyspark. I tried use `union` or `crossJoin` on dataframe, but this is very complicated for me at the moment. I would like to do this task with use `pyspark`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some methods you can try:

### Method-1: string functions: [repeat](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.repeat), [substring](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.substring)

1. calculate number of repeats `n = ceil(session_duration/24)`
2. create a string `a` which repeats the substring `8,` for `n` times and then use *substring()* or *regexp_replace()* to remove the trailing comma `,`
3. split `a` by comma and then posexplode it into rows of `pos` and `session_duration`
4. adjust the start_date by `pos` from the above step
5. cast the string `session_duration` into `double`

see below code example:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# assume the columns in your dataframe are read with proper data types
# for example using inferSchema=True
df = spark.read.csv('/path/to/file', header=True, inferSchema=True)

df1 = df.withColumn('n', F.ceil(F.col('session_duration')/24).astype('int')) \
        .withColumn('a', F.when(F.col('n')>1, F.expr('substring(repeat("8,",n),0,2*n-1)')).otherwise(F.col('session_duration')))

>>> df1.show()
+---------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-------------------+---+-------+
|client_username|workstation|session_duration|access_point_name|         start_date|  n|      a|
+---------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-------------------+---+-------+
|         XX1@AD|      Apple|            1.55|            idf_1|2019-06-01 00:00:00|  1|   1.55|
|         XX2@AD|      Apple|           30.12|            idf_2|2019-06-04 00:00:00|  2|    8,8|
|         XX3@AD|      Apple|           78.25|            idf_3|2019-06-02 00:00:00|  4|8,8,8,8|
|         XX4@AD|      Apple|            0.45|            idf_1|2019-06-02 00:00:00|  1|   0.45|
|         XX1@AD|      Apple|           23.11|            idf_1|2019-06-02 00:00:00|  1|  23.11|
+---------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-------------------+---+-------+

df_new = df1.select(
          'client_username'
        , 'workstation'
        , F.posexplode(F.split('a', ',')).alias('pos', 'session_duration')
        , 'access_point_name'
        , F.expr('date_add(start_date, pos)').alias('start_date')
    ).drop('pos')

>>> df_new.show()
+---------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+----------+
|client_username|workstation|session_duration|access_point_name|start_date|
+---------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+----------+
|         XX1@AD|      Apple|            1.55|            idf_1|2019-06-01|
|         XX2@AD|      Apple|               8|            idf_2|2019-06-04|
|         XX2@AD|      Apple|               8|            idf_2|2019-06-05|
|         XX3@AD|      Apple|               8|            idf_3|2019-06-02|
|         XX3@AD|      Apple|               8|            idf_3|2019-06-03|
|         XX3@AD|      Apple|               8|            idf_3|2019-06-04|
|         XX3@AD|      Apple|               8|            idf_3|2019-06-05|
|         XX4@AD|      Apple|            0.45|            idf_1|2019-06-02|
|         XX1@AD|      Apple|           23.11|            idf_1|2019-06-02|
+---------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+----------+
```

The above code can also be written into one chain:

```
df_new = df.withColumn('n'
                , F.ceil(F.col('session_duration')/24).astype('int')
          ).withColumn('a'
                , F.when(F.col('n')>1, F.expr('substring(repeat("8,",n),0,2*n-1)')).otherwise(F.col('session_duration'))
          ).select('client_username'
                , 'workstation'
                , F.posexplode(F.split('a', ',')).alias('pos', 'session_duration')
                , 'access_point_name'
                , F.expr('date_add(start_date, pos)').alias('start_date')
          ).withColumn('session_duration'
                , F.col('session_duration').astype('double')
          ).drop('pos')
```

### Method-2: array function [array_repeat](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.array_repeat) (pyspark 2.4+)

Similar to the Method-1, but `a` is already an array thus no need to split a string into array:

```
df1 = df.withColumn('n', F.ceil(F.col('session_duration')/24).astype('int')) \
        .withColumn('a', F.when(F.col('n')>1, F.expr('array_repeat(8,n)')).otherwise(F.array('session_duration')))

>>> df1.show()
+---------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-------------------+---+--------------------+
|client_username|workstation|session_duration|access_point_name|         start_date|  n|                   a|
+---------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-------------------+---+--------------------+
|         XX1@AD|      Apple|            1.55|            idf_1|2019-06-01 00:00:00|  1|              [1.55]|
|         XX2@AD|      Apple|           30.12|            idf_2|2019-06-04 00:00:00|  2|          [8.0, 8.0]|
|         XX3@AD|      Apple|           78.25|            idf_3|2019-06-02 00:00:00|  4|[8.0, 8.0, 8.0, 8.0]|
|         XX4@AD|      Apple|            0.45|            idf_1|2019-06-02 00:00:00|  1|              [0.45]|
|         XX1@AD|      Apple|           23.11|            idf_1|2019-06-02 00:00:00|  1|             [23.11]|
+---------------+-----------+----------------+-----------------+-------------------+---+--------------------+

df_new = df1.select('client_username'
            , 'workstation'
            , F.posexplode('a').alias('pos', 'session_duration')
            , 'access_point_name'
            , F.expr('date_add(start_date, pos)').alias('start_date')
       ).drop('pos')
```